# Can you get a second chance

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

In the trials of Osiris for Destiny do you get a second chance? Say you went 9 and 1, can you still get the secret social place on Mercury or no?

Comment: Do you mean having your scorecard display 9 wins and 1 loss, or it displaying 9 wins and your loss being the "forgiven" loss (it doesn't display)?

Comment: 9 and 1. I didn't know that there's a forgiven loss, I didn't get the DLC expansion yet I'm going to pree order the legendary edition for TTK

Answer (score 1):

You only reach the social space by going "Flawless" which means your card has none of the red circles indicating a loss colored in.

There are some "Boons" you can buy to help you achieve this:

- Start with a free win
- If you win your next game, it will count as two wins
- Your next loss is forgiven and will not be counted against you

Buying these 3 boons means you can techincally go at least 7-1 and still go "Flawless".

Answer (score 0):

If you do not make it to the lighthouse by going undefeated you can always try again. Only losing one match is pretty good so that is definitely close, you would want to try again in that circumstance.

Even if you lose your first match you can start over right then and there, or even if you do make it to the lighthouse.

The only requirement is that you burn your card by deleting it or turning it in if complete, and get a new one. From that point you may continue on to attempt to reach the lighthouse or any of the other rewards available for that week.

You can even make it to the lighthouse multiple times if you are in to that sort of thing. However, after the first time that week (per character) all you can do there is dance because you already opened the rewards chest. Similar to other rewards schemes such as raiding or the nightfall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get a second chance at Trials. If you fail that time, you can go a third time. You can always do Trials over and over again.

I hope this helped. Good luck Guardian.